# get new access_token for google calendar api js

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I use google calendar in my application. I get access token and it works fine. this is the code

```
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().grantOfflineAccess().then(function(resp){
            $.ajax({ 
                url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    'code'  : resp.code,
                    'client_id'     : CLIENT_ID,
                    'client_secret' : CLIENT_SECRET,
                    'redirect_uri'  : "https://calendar.myapp.com",
                    'grant_type'    : "authorization_code"
                    },
                success: function(x){                         
                 console.log(x);
                }
            })
        });
```

This returns refresh token and access token. But when access token expires I need to get a new token. This is my code for a new access token

```
$.ajax({ 
                url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
                type: 'POST',                                        
                datatype : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
                data: {
                    'client_id'     : CLIENT_ID, 
               'redirect_uri':'https://calendar.myapp.com',
                    'client_secret' : CLIENT_SECRET,
                    'grant_type'    : "refresh_token",       
                    'refresh_token': refreshToken
                    },
                success: function(x){ ;
                    console.log(x);
                }
            })
```

But it returns an error `POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token 400 ()`
I tried everything from the documentation but couldn't find the solution.

Comment: did you configured you'r app as an offline app?

Comment: I think that `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().grantOfflineAccess()` means that app is offline. Doesn't it?